# Android Status bar multiline Notification API 14

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-statusbar

I'm using API 14 device. I have been trying to develop the multiline notification similar to Gmail notifications. I have gone through several stack overflow questions but didn't find any solution which would give me multiline notification for API<16. **Please note that Big view notification works only for OS 4.1+ and I want this for API 14.**

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle;
    inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine("Hello 1")
    .addLine("Hello 2")
    .addLine("Hello 3")
    .addLine("Hello 4");

    builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    builder.setTicker("HELLO WORLD MSG");
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
    builder.setContentTitle("HELLO WORLD");
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    notificationManager.notify(1000, builder.build());
```

[image: This is the result I obtained. Here strings "hello 1", "hello2", "hell3" etc are not visible]

I am not getting Strings "hello 1", "hello 2", ... in separate lines. Please Help me...

**EDIT: Since many wrong solutions have been posted, I would like to point out that the multiline notifications are working fine in other modern mobiles(nexus). The code I posted is not faulty/buggy. But it doesn't work for API 14.**

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
String[] names=new String[5];
        names[0]="Hello 1";
        names[1]="Hello 2";
        names[2]="Hello 3";
        names[3]="Hello 4";
        names[4]="Hello 5";
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Hello");
        for (String name:names)
        {
            inboxStyle.addLine(name);
        }

        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
```

OR, you can also refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Dude take a look at the code properly please!!!                                          I have already added inboxStyle.addLine("Hello 1")
    .addLine("Hello 2")
    .addLine("Hello 3")
    .addLine("Hello 4");   This is more or less what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I will not recommend API14 (as it is obsolete), but if you still want to have multiple line notification,you can have by using `Notification.InboxStyle`

```
Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();     
String[] events = new String[]{"h1","h2","h3","h4"};                //your lines
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
for(int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {
   inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pintent)
        .setStyle(inboxStyle)           
        .build();
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle)

Comment: Dude you are just trying to add the strings in a loop whereas I'm adding them one by one using builder pattern. inboxStyle.addLine("Hello 1") .addLine("Hello 2") .addLine("Hello 3") .addLine("Hello 4");  Please look again. This is not an appropriate solution.